# Send notification e-mail after new content was added

Tags: 7, notifications

Some people refuse to learn about RSS and wish they could give me (e.g., via some form) e-mail (without registration) and they would be automatically notified about new content.

Could you help me how to achieve this functionality in Drupal 7? I heard about three modules that could help : Rules, Subscriptions and Notify. Only the first works under Drupal 7. Could you configure this functionality with some suitable module?

Comment: When you say "without registration," do you mean that they want to be able to get notified of new content without to have an account on your site?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, exactly, it's strange requirement. They don't want to have registered users but they want e-mail notification. I understand that this is little cumbersome (it's site for a company and visitors will be their employers), so I guess I should collect their e-mails and then don't accept new e-mails because of spam possibility.

Comment: It's quite a strange requirement, which eliminate many possible candidates.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) is best for this, it depends on Entity API.

- Simple download and enable them from Admin -> Modules
- Now follow Admin -> Configuration -> Workflow -> Rules
- Click on `Add new rule`
- Define name e.g. `"New content email notification"` , select `'After Saving new content'` from React on event select box and hit the Save
- On the next page, event is already defined, No condition is required to define here, Head on to Action section and hit `Add action`
- Enter recipient email address in the `To` field box
- Populate Subject and Message, From fields. (A number of Replacement pattern are available to include in the text)

e.g. New content [node:title] added by [node:author] of type [node:type] on [node:created].

- Hit the save
- On the settings fieldset, make sure to check `Active` check box.

Comment: Thank you for this perfect answer. It works but it only writes this error message after creating a new content `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in node_tokens() (line 140 of /var/www/modules/node/node.tokens.inc).` do you think I can repair this?

Comment: And saving new content is very slow now. It seems that it sends e-mail while saving. I looked into configuration if I can send an e-mail 2 minutes after creating new node but seems there is not such option.

Answer (score 7):

...alternatively, if you need to do this programmatically (not via [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) module), you can hook into [hook_node_insert()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_insert/7) and grab the $node object, then do with it what you want.

Answer (score 2):

[Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) will do exactly this:

> Example use cases
>   - Build flexible content publishing workflows changes
>   - Send customized mails to notify your users about important
>   - Create custom redirections, system messages, breadcrumbs, ...

Do you need help configuring it ?

Comment: If you have experience with configuration it would be kind of you. I wasn't sure that it will work the way I need, so I rather asked.

Comment: How can i make system send notification from rule for example every 2h and sum up all new content made ? Not sure should i make new question for this..