# Send mail to email addresses from webform when a content is saved

Tags: rules, webforms

I want exactly like this [Send notification e-mail after new content was added](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/5136/send-notification-e-mail-after-new-content-was-added) but the answer is not seems to be question specific. I have a webform where I get email id of the anonymous users and I want to send email to those ids when I save a new content.

I have combined Rules and webform rules for it. I created an

**event**
-*After saving new content*

**Condition** 
-*Content is of type*

**Actions** 
-*Fetch webform submissions of node ID n*

**Loop** 
-*fetched submissions*

**loop action** 
-*Send mail*.

But i am stuck to move forward as I am not able to configure 'TO' field with email fields from fetched submissions.

Comment: Are you trying the replacement patterns?

Comment: I tried data selector but it gives the error data does not match. Not sure which one to use

Comment: your replacement pattern will look like `[node:field-name_of_field]`. Just put this in the "To" field.

Comment: I couldn't find such a token in replacement pattern. I actually wanted to get the submitted email ids in the TO field. In loop, the current list item is current_submission and how can i get the email from that?

Comment: then try fetching the data manually `<?php print $data['components']['email']['value'][0]; ?>` and please read the **note** on [webform rules module.](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules)

Comment: You mean to enter this code in the TO field in the UI? And why the list item is not available in the token list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enabled the PHP filter module and the list item is available in the PHP evaluation area. So fetch the email is as `<?php print $list_item->data['component_id']['value'][0]; ?>`. Works pretty well :)

Comment: Check the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to "***Enabled the PHP filter***" (as in your own answer) to get this to work. Read on for an alternative solution ...

You do have access to all ***labels*** and all ***values*** of any field of a webform, ie:

- `[data:MachineFieldName-title]` contains the **Label** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName.
- `[data:MachineFieldName-value]` contains the **Value** of a field with machine name MachineFieldName

So in your case, you should be able to get it to work using something like `[data:email-id]` (assuming that's what corresponds to the "*email id of the anonymous users*" in your case).

For way more details on this, and a prototype rule about this, refer to the answer to "[How to create a node from a Webform using rules?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/199821/how-to-create-a-node-from-a-webform-using-rules/199825#199825)":

- the *1st attempt* relates to using "Entity has field" (which doesn't work for [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform))
- the *2nd attempt* explains what to do in case of [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform).