# Pull webform submissions in different webistes to one end-point

Tags: 7, webforms, drush

hypothetical example:

website1 has 2 webforms, I need to access the submissions of the 2 webforms in another website2

So if an user send the webform in website1 I need to log in as admin in website2 and see that submission. In few words, pull the webform submissions to one endpoint website (without the necessity of click a button or run a command), Master-Slave where the slave is the endpoint website that is only going to show results of webforms.

is this possible?

My use case: I have a lot of surveys in different websites hosted in different servers, I need an endpoint where to collect all the results and show it to my users, so I need have the submissions stored in my endpoint website for show results to my users.

Thanks

Comment: I found this module https://www.drupal.org/project/entitysync but I could not set it up for sync the webforms, it has an advantage and is that uses rules, but I do not know the set up for webforms =/

Comment: After a lot of testing entitysync do not work properly, a lot of bugs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A stupid and simple approach (that scales badly) would be to use drush sql-sync.

Since you can give it the `--tables-list` option, you can get it to transfer only the appropriate tables. And because drush will use rsync for transfer, the network transfer is not going to be very large, since only changes well be moved.

It will however drop and recreate the tables everytime, and this might not be acceptable.

Comment: Thank you it worked like a charm, instead of make the command run everytime an user sends a webform, It is executed each cron run, so the performance is not affected a great deal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, there are several ways to accomplish a 'sync' across multiple sites.
However, without more technical information the options are generic at best.  Webforms that include uploads or images may require additional work to configure.

Bottom line, the webform data lives in a table in the database, on each site.  The best solution may not be a module but rather a cron job pulling that data and serializing it on a collection site.  This would be a custom script collating and creating webform content on the collection site.  As such, the webform Node ID would not necessarily be preserved.

Another approach, if the cron job is not preferred... might be to use the built-in mail function from webform, or to create a Rule to send the webform data to a mailbox.  The collection site can be configured to create node content processed from that mailbox.  One benefit is that this could be a non-webform content type.  As such, you can add fields and act on that data in a way to manage it and you could also in this way preserve a record of the original Node ID so that a reference to the source site is possible.  Other fields might be the site URL, notes, if action is required... and so forth.

Here are some references that might be useful in the latter approach:

- Add content to your site via email using https://www.drupal.org/project/mailhandler - Mailhandler
- http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/69134/send-mail-to-email-addresses-from-webform-when-a-content-is-saved - Send mail to email addresses from webform ...
- https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules - Webform Rules module

Of course, it matters if you're using D6 or D7.  [Mailsave & Mailhandler are both included in one popular approach using D6](https://www.drupal.org/node/200702) and [Mailsave](https://www.drupal.org/project/mailsave) doesn't have a D7 version.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, well your option is a good idea, but the fact is that I need to have data as the submissions of the webforms instead of nodes, for take advantage of the analisys tools that offers webform, Thanks however I will wait if someone has another idea. Thanks

Comment: What analysis is required for transfer? Bottom line - if you're looking to transfer tables @Letharion mentioned rsync/drush as one option in the cron approach I was referring to earlier in the answer... Although there are *many* ways to handle the issues with direct table transfer. Bottom line, if there is some type of analysis you wish to transfer as well then it will exist in the tables and your answer is not going to be simple.